# Invoke a shell script execution using nagios

Tags: shell, automation, sh, nagios

Hi all I am having a script which  restarts all the components(.jar files) present in the server `(/scripts/startAll.sh)`. So whenever my server goes down, I want to  invoke the execution of the script using nagios, which is running on different linux server. is it possible to do so? kindly help on How to invoke execution of this script using nagios?

Comment: Why do you want to use Nagios to start you services? Take a look at upstart (http://upstart.ubuntu.com), it is very easy to configure and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Event Handlers**

Nagios and Naemon allow executing custom scripts, both for hosts and for services entering a 'problem state.'  Since your implementation is for restarting specific applications, yours will most likely need to be service event handlers.

*From [Nagios Documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html):*

> Event handlers can be enabled or disabled on a program-wide basis by
>   using the enable_event_handlers in your main configuration file.
>
> Host- and service-specific event handlers can be enabled or disabled
>   by using the event_handler_enabled directive in your host and service
>   definitions. Host- and service-specific event handlers will not be
>   executed if the global enable_event_handlers option is disabled.

---

**Enabling and Creating Event Handler Commands for a Service or Host**

1. First, enable event handlers by modifying or adding the following line to your Nagios config file.

[IE: /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg]:

`enable_event_handlers=1`

2. Define and enable an event handler on the service failure(s) that will trigger the script.  Do so by adding two `event_handler` directives inside of the service you've already defined.

[IE: /usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg]:

```
define service{
    host_name       my-server
    service_description my-check
    check_command       my-check-command!arg1!arg2!etc
    ....
    event_handler my-eventhandler
    event_handler_enabled   1
    }
```

3. The last step is to create the event_handler command named in step 2, and point it to a script you've already created.  There are a few approaches to this (SSH, NRPE, Locally-Hosted, Remotely Hosted).  I'll use the simplest method, hosting a BASH script on the monitor system that will connect via SSH and execute:

[IE: /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg]:

```
 define command{

        command_name    my-eventhandler

        command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/my-eventhandler.sh

        }
```

In this example, the script "my-eventhandler.sh" should use SSH to connect to the remote system, and execute the commands you've decided on.

**NOTE:** This is only intended as a quick, working solution for **one box** in your environment.  In practice, it is better to create an event handler script remotely, and to use an agent such as NRPE to execute the command while passing a `$HOSTNAME$` variable (thus allowing the solution to scale across more than one system).  The simplest tutorial I've found for using NRPE to execute an event handler can be found [here](http://www.it-slav.net/blogs/2009/06/15/using-nagios-or-op5-monitor-eventhandler-to-start-a-service-that-has-stopped/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. you mean to say that I should create another shell script locally on my Nagios system. and using that (`my-eventhandler.sh` ) script I should invoke the execution of shell script(startAll.sh) present in my remote linux server.

Comment: That would work, yes.  Beware, you will need to deal with sudo access on the remote system, and that sometimes requires disabling "requiretty" in your sudoers file.  @ /etc/sudoers, you can safely disable this for nagios + nrpe using  `Defaults:nagios !requiretty` and `Defaults:nrpe !requiretty` (assuming nagios/nrpe are the users)

Comment: I tried to vote when I read your post, but I don't have threshold reputation to vote. sorry..!!! votes =100000....

Comment: I upvoted your comment, maybe that will help your rep! :)  I think accepting an answer helps, too. ;) *hint*

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell scripts on remote hosts by snmpd using **check_by_snmp.pl**

Take a view to https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/*-Remote-Check-Tunneling/check_by_snmp--2F-check_snmp_extend--2F-check_snmp_exec/details

This is a very useful plugin for nagios. I work with this a lot.

Good luck!!